# ActionBar doesn't fully hide (only does the text & buttons)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, appbar

I've searched for solutions but don't seem to find any answer for my issue. I navigated several potential solutions I found here but all of them ended up with the same issue.

**Context:** I have a `FragmentContainer` that holds a `Viewpager` with `RecyclerView` in each page. When I click an item in the `RecyclerView`, it opens a new different `FragmentContainer2` with a `ViewPager` that holds the detail of the selected card and I can swipe reading the different cards.

**What I want to do:** when I select an item in the `RecyclerView`, I want the `appBar` GONE.

**Problem:** when I hit any item of the `RecyclerView` and the new `ViewPager` loads, the `appBar` buttons and title are gone, but not the background!

Here there are two screenshots of the states of `appBar` in one `ViewPager` and the other:

`FragmentContainer` that holds a `ViewPager` with a `RecyclerView`:

[image: FragmentContainer that Holds a ViewPager with RecyclerView:]

`FragmentContainer` that holds a `ViewPager` with the news detail:

[image: FragmentContainer that holds a ViewPager with the news detail]

**METHOD TO SHOW AND HIDE TOOLBAR/FLOATING ACTION BUTTON:**

```
    public void setToolbarAndFabVisibility(Boolean trueOrFale){

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if(trueOrFale!=null){
        if(trueOrFale){
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.hide();
            }
            fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu" />
```

**app_bar_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_pressed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/favourite_button"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fragment_container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Both xml are closed with appropiate tags. For some reason preview here doesn't show.

Any idea where I might be failing? I have everything in one activity.

Let me know if there's anything else I can post here that might help. Thanks for taking the time.

**EDIT;**
sorry, I forgot to include the toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:elevation="16dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/favourites_button"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/favourite_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bookmarked_button"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bookmarked_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/history_button"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_history_white_24dp" />
```

Comment: Please, next time after solving your problem come back to post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks. I tried this before and had the same result, black bar won't disappear. I just realised that I had a method prior to this that changed the color of the appbar and did actually work. The method is still alive, so the appbar should be a different color (same as background in the detailed screen). Any idea if the issue could be on other place?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are dealing with **two** action bars:

One is provided by the system through a theme like `@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` 
and the other is declared in your `app_bar_main.xml`.

`getSupportActionBar().hide()` only hides the action bar that is provided by the system.

Check the theme that is set in the application manifest and consult the documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Comment: hey Volker, thanks for taking the time to check this out. In my manifest I have `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` that leads to the styles.xml, and the style is: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`. This gave me some direction though. It seems that making the action bar disappear works, but it is leaving a "hole". I'm checking this out and it seems to be offset!

Comment: In your toolbar.xml your are using android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" 
Maybe that's somehow interfering with the main theme...

Comment: I deleted the appbar container and seems to work ok. I'll test a while and edit asap. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

if

```
getActionbar().hide();
getActionbar().show();
```

doesn't work then try

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

It will work.or try to use toolbar

Comment: Originally I had this:  `if(trueOrFalse!=null){ if(trueOrFalse){ toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }else{ toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE); fab.setVisibility(View.GONE); } }`  but results in the same way. I also tried what you suggested. All have the same result. The black empty bar there. EDIT; sorry, can't make this code look good. Can't insert new line! Enter publishes my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was issuing this same problem. ActionBar was being overridden and that's why it leaves a black gap when `hide()` is called.

Fix:

*styles.xml:*

```
   <style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

*AndroidManifest.xml:*

```
<activity android:name="com.stonetree.supercart.controller.activities.SuperCart"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
```

Make sure to call on your manifest the proper style name which has windowActionBar set to false.

*Activity.xml:*

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Add Toolbar to your layout. Make sure to call dependencies to compile android.support.v7.widget.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Watch out for version and further minor details. Moving on...

*Activity.java:*

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
}
```

In my case, my menu was separated on xml. A custom menu.

*Menu.xml:*

```
      <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemId"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync"
        android:title="Menu item"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

Also call on *Activity.java*:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.supercart_app_bar, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Now Toolbar has your custom layout from Menu.xml - Just call `hide()` or `show()` wherever your want and the Bar will act like visibility is set to `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE`.